php script with accented characters or spaces in filename path not found by apache
On my Apache web server I have a few (file system) paths that contain spaces or accented characters, such as é, á, or ö. The web server returns "File not found." if (1) the path contains a space or one of the accented characters, and (2) the file that is retrieved is a php script. If the path has none of these characters, then the php script is run correctly, and also if the path has these characters, but an html-file is loaded.
I made a minimal example with two paths, where the only difference is an "e" or an "é" in the path, and both contain the same php and html files. Retrieving them gives in the ssl_access_log:
192.168.178.11 - MM [12/Oct/2024:21:49:47 +0200] "GET /test/urlenc_w_php/e/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 360
192.168.178.11 - MM [12/Oct/2024:21:49:51 +0200] "GET /test/urlenc_w_php/e/index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.178.11 - MM [12/Oct/2024:21:49:54 +0200] "GET /test/urlenc_w_php/%C3%A9/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 16
192.168.178.11 - MM [12/Oct/2024:21:49:56 +0200] "GET /test/urlenc_w_php/%C3%A9/index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -


where %C3%A9 is the encoded 'é'. The above lines show that the combination of 'é' in the path and the php script gives a 404.
I suspect an encoding issue, but have no idea how to diagnose further or fix.
Maybe relevant: the "File not found." message is different from when I type an url that points to a file that really doesn't exist. In that
case I get "Not Found" "The requested URL was not found on this server." which is apparently generated by a different process.
The php code is (although, not sure whether it's relevant) index.php:
<?php
echo <<<END
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<a href=index.php>PHP</a>
<a href=index.html>HTML</a>
</body>
</html>
END;
?> 

The html file is exactly the same as what is output by the php code.
The path entered in the browser looks like https://<server name>/test/urlenc_w_php/e/index.php or with 'é', with ...html. The links in the scripts point to themselves and give the same results.

Could you add the PHP script to your question? Having code is somewhat essential when asking a coding question.

I added the php code, but please note the code does work for the case when the path contains the 'e'. I expect the cause is related the the path encoding, and to the fact that it is a php file, not the actual contents of the file. The error occurs also with other php files.

@KIKOSoftware This isn't a coding question, it's an Apache question. It's never even running the script because it can't find the file.

OK, so are the paths entered into the address bar of a browser? I can't tell. If so, what do those paths look like?

I added to the question a description of the paths entered. I actually suspect that for some reason in case of the php script, Apache looks for the encoded path instead of the decoded path. The error log contains the encoded path, but before the file (html or php) can be found, it needs to be decoded.

Thanks for your edit. Yes, I can reproduce this with my browser and web server. When I serve a path in which the é is replaced by %c3%a9 then it works, but it does look ugly. I'm currently not sure how well the web can cope with non-ascii characters. In case you're using a router in your application you could simply use rawurldecode() to undo the damage, but I guess that's not the case for you.

I did find this suggestion for a rewrite rule in .htaccess, but it's old and rather ugly.

Why do you have special characters in your path to begin with? That's looking for troubles.

@Olivier They are only called "special characters" because they're unusual in English. Other languages will give you quite a different perspective. I think that for aNDy the only trouble is how to work on the web server with encoded characters. This should be a solved problem by now.

If you're using FastCGI: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/15246

Thanks for the testing and the suggestion about the rewrite rule. Regarding the testing: most (all?) modern browsers should be able to cope with utf-8 characters. As far as I know, it is the browser that encodes the utf-8 string before sending it to the server, but your test suggests differently. Unfortunately, for me neither of the urls work. Regarding the rewrite: the linked page converts win-1252 to utf-8, but in my case it is already in utf-8 (and that is probably the problem). Nevertheless, I tried RewriteRule "^urlenc_w_php/e/(.+)" "urlenc_w_php/é/$1" [NE] , but the problem persists.

Just seeing Olivier's comment. I'll check, thanks!

The workaround in Olivier's link word for me. So apparently this is a bug. I wasn't aware that I was using FastCGI, but I am, which can be confirmed by the output of phpinfo(); Thanks for the help. Should this be made an answer somehow?
